# Default class folder in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the default class folder in `Xamarin.Forms`?

In web development solution there is `App_Code` folder, where should I use in Xamarin.Forms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can organize your code however you like.  You can place everything in the root folder, or create separate (even nested) folders.  Xamarin Forms does not require any special folder structure.

I tend to use a structure like this, but this is solely my preference:

```
Root 
 - Model
 - View
 - ViewModel
 - Service
 - Data
```